# Relation does not exist after switch from database postgres to smart_brain

Tags: postgresql

After switching databases, my table does no longer exist:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM users;
 id | name | email | entries | joined
----+------+-------+---------+--------
(0 rows)

postgres=# \c smart_brain
You are now connected to database "smart_brain" as user "postgres".
smart_brain=# SELECT * FROM users;
ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM users;
                      ^
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, It seems table/view users does not exists, can you confirm if otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is as expected. You created a table in the database `postgres`, not in `smart_brain`. Consequently, you cannot use the table in the latter database.

Databases are strictly logically separated in PostgreSQL.

I recommended that you don't create user objects in `postgres`, but only use that database for administrative purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding quotes : `SELECT * FROM "Users"`